# LIBGDX- getting position of an actor inside a table

Tags: libgdx

Well the title says it all, I want to get the position of an actor inside a table

> Button button = new Button(bs);
>
> table.add(button).width(50).height(50);
>
> table.top().center();

Thanks in advance.

edit: with `button.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(button.getX(), button.getY()));`
i get a near position but not exact, here is an screen shot, red squares are the positions im getting, while the transparent squares are the buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
button.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(button.getX(), button.getY()));
```

This should return a Vector2 with the real position. I think that the table.validate() should be called before you can get the position of your button.

validate() calls layout(). layout() will be automatically called on the next draw after you create the table. If you need the position right after the initialization of the table - I think that you will need to call the layout() method.

*layout() description:*

> Computes and caches any information needed for drawing and, if this actor has children, positions and sizes each child, calls invalidate() any each child whose width or height has changed, and calls validate() on each child. This method should almost never be called directly, instead validate() should be used. 
>   Overrides: layout() in WidgetGroup

*validate() description:*

> Ensures the actor has been laid out. Calls layout() if invalidate() has been called since the last time validate() was called, or if the actor otherwise needs to be laid out. This method is usually called in Actor.draw(Batch, float) before drawing is performed. 
>   Specified by: validate() in Layout

Comment: this is suposing my stage has no specified viewport? because mine has, I will tried it when I get home

Comment: Every stage has viewport. If you don't specify one, ScalingViewport will be created

Comment: what im trying to say its how the method localToStageCoordinates will know what stage coordinates i want since a stage with a specified viewport coordinates wont be the same as stage without a specified viewport, btw I tried it and it give me a near position but not a exact position.

Comment: I posted a screen shot now c:

Answer (score 3):

Okay I manage to do it like this:

```
button.localToParentCoordinates(new Vector2(table.getX(), table.getY()));
```

Thanks Yasen Bagalev, for pointing me to the right direction.